# Sliding control in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have developed wp8 app and looking for a control to slide. I am showing single verse in the page and I want the user to slide (forward and backward) to show next verse, verses may reach 286. I have seen this feature in many application in windows phone store, but I don't what wp8 control they are using.

appreciate your feedback!

Comment: you could use pivot or panorama control to achieve forward and backward functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panorama is that you have one image in the background you move a little everytime you go to one side, it is what is used in the image app.

But since you need 286, you should not use the panorama control. Then you should rely on the pivot but beware of microsoft not wanting the users to be confused and caught inside 286 pages, so you need to give the user and overview and use a button that can return a person to the start page.

Comment: Thanks, I think this could be solution, but Microsoft suggests that pivot should not be used when sliding exceed 7 items. (This was a concern for me)

Comment: Exactly, so I heard somebody passed certification by using an applicationbar with a navigation button maybe also a counter in the corner showing where the person is. If it is the solution then please mark as answer